# How to connect python with vertica using ODBC?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, vertica

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
conn = "vertica+pyodbc://dbadmin:password@VMart"
sa.create_engine(conn, pool_size=10, max_overflow=20)
%load_ext sql
%sql vertica+pyodbc://VMart
```

error

> (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver
>   Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
>   (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)
Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:

> ```
>  postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname<br>
>            or an existing connection: dict_keys([])
> ```

First

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import urllib
sa.create_engine('vertica+vertica_python://dbadmin:password@192.168.11.132:5433/VMart')
%load_ext sql
%sql vertica+pyodbc://VMart
```

Second

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
sa.create_engine('vertica+vertica_python://dbadmin:password@VMart')

import pyodbc
```

Third

```
conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER=Vertica;SERVER=192.168.11.132;DATABASE=VMart;PORT=5433;UID=dbadmin;PWD=password")
```

same error

> error but I already test vertica odbc in windows10. It connect
>   successfuled

(pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)
Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:

> postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname
>                  or an existing connection: dict_keys([])

Answer (score 0):

Might not get to the root of your problem, but below are a few steps that could help in making a connection:

1. Have you tried installing `sqlalchemy-vertica` driver?. Specifically I would recommend installing with `vertica-python`. This is one driver for the connection with vertica in python and I found it works pretty well (caveats later)

```sh
pip install sqlalchemy-vertica[vertica-python]
```

2. Have you imported `vertica-python`? Not sure this will impact the code, but it definitely helps to remove as an issue. In case you have not installed it:

```sh
pip install vertica-python
```

**Edit**: As a matter of fact if all you need is to read data, this package worked well for me on itself. Below is a sample code that is currently working for me:

```py
import vertica_python
conn_info = {
    'host': 'host-ip',
    'port': port,
    'user': 'usr',
    'password':password,
    'database': 'db',
    # autogenerated session label by default,
    'session_label': 'current_session',
    # default throw error on invalid UTF-8 results
    'unicode_error': 'strict',
    # SSL is disabled by default
    'ssl': False,
    # using server-side prepared statements is disabled by default
    'use_prepared_statements': False,
    # connection timeout is not enabled by default
    # 'connection_timeout': 1
}

vertica_python.connect(**conn_info)
```

3. Making the connection. I would recommend your first line to connect:

```py
sa.create_engine('vertica+vertica_python://dbadmin:password@192.168.11.132:5433/VMart')
```

**Caveats using Pandas**:

1. I had issues with sending `str` variables to the db using `pandas.to_sql`. If that is your case, just make sure to pass the types explicitly for those columns as `VARCHAR` (it will force to `TEXT` for some reason). This function from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51260504/unable-to-write-data-to-vertica-database-using-python-sqlalchemy-type-text-d) might help you:

```py
def updateType(df_para):
    dtypedict = {}  # create and empty dictionary
    for i,j in zip(df_para.columns, df_para.dtypes):
        if "object" in str(j):
            dtypedict.update({i: sa.types.VARCHAR})

    return dtypedict

updatedict = updateType(df)
```

2. I would receive a weird error when using `to_sql`:

> NotImplementedError: executemany is implemented for simple INSERT statements only.

Did not find a proper solution but tried to remediate it using the `chunksize` param, and it seems to have worked.

Comment: Thank for your help. 
I have already tried it before and I just reinstall anaconda-navigator. Would I miss any libraries? 
1. conda update sqlalchemy
2. pip install sqlalchemy-vertica[pyodbc,vertica-python]
3. pip install pyodbc
4.pip install ipython-sql
5. pip install psycopg2
6. pip install six

However, it stills the same error again. I try to find it out and I don't get closed. Anything may suggest me

Comment: Thank for your help. 
I have already tried it before and I just reinstall anaconda-navigator. Would I miss any libraries? 
1. conda update sqlalchemy
2. pip install sqlalchemy-vertica[pyodbc,vertica-python]
3. pip install pyodbc
4.pip install ipython-sql
5. pip install psycopg2
6. pip install six

import sqlalchemy as sa
import urllib
sa.create_engine('vertica+vertica_python://dbadmin:password@192.168.11.132:5433/VMart')
%load_ext sql
%sql vertica+pyodbc://VMart

However, it stills the same error again. I try to find it out and I don't get closed. Anything may suggest me

Comment: Hi @ChirametCharoennakasit I dont see in your list `vertica_python`  itself [here](https://github.com/vertica/vertica-python). It is a good package and connected to the example provided above. I just managed to connect yesterday and it worked well. As a matter of fact, if all you need is to read data, you should only need this package. I edited the answer to add a code snippet that is working for me to read data.

Comment: It is working now but I have to use it another way. I would like to use sqlalchemy